# Forgot pragma pack(pop) program crashes

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma-pack

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef enum __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
    ETypeZero = 0,
    ETypeOne,
    ETypeTwo,
    ETypeUndefined
} ESomeType;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In my code above, I had accidentally forgot `#pragma pack(pop)`, and I saw some other data down the line getting corrupted. Why would that have occurred?
Also, is there a GCC flag that can detect the missing pop?

Comment: "*I saw some other data down the line getting corrupted. Why would that have occurred?*" - Why do you think it *wouldn't* have occurred? The `pragma` takes effect on all subsequent code until you turn it off, or the file ends. So, you altered the alignment of not just your `enum`, but of all other subsequent data as well. And that other data was likely used in places that expected it to have a different alignment than you specified.

Comment: In any case, why are you using `#pragma pack(push, 1)` together with `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` at all? That is redundant. Use one or the other, not both. Use `#pragma pack` for whole blocks of code. Use `__attribute__ ((packed))` on specific variables/types.